Insert lists into DataFrame cells
Look at this code:
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[['a','b'],['c','d']],columns=['B','C'])
df.insert(loc=0,column='A',value='Hello world!')

What it does: It inserts a new column named 'A' and writes 'Hello world!' into each cell of that new columns. But now watch this:
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[['a','b'],['c','d']],columns=['B','C'])
df.insert(loc=0,column='A',value=['Hello','world!'])

Here we obtain a new column named 'A' again, but this time we get 'Hello' in the first cell and 'world!' in the second. However, I want to have the list ['Hello','world!'] in both cells. How do I modify the call of the insert function to obtain what I want?

Pandas is not designed to work with lists, you have to encapsulate the values to assign in a Series

@mozway How do I do that?

There are different ways, check the duplicate

@mozway Actually, all ways are similar. The list is multiplied.
